# Finding a div in a text variable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I have a text variable in Javascript. Its name is `text`. It contains a whole HTML document. I've tried to find a jQuery selector that matches a contained div with id "mainContent":

```
var innerText = text.find('div[id=mainContent]');
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. The JavaScript somehow breaks at this point.
I've also tried it with:

```
var innerText = $(text).find('div[id=mainContent]');
```

But this also does break the JavaScript flow.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: When you say `text` contains a complete/whole HTML document: do you mean it is a String? Or is it a valid HTML element, such as `body`?

Comment: If `text` contains a string value, you cannot use jQuery to search through it, you'll need to use string-based search methods, like regular expressions for example (depends how complicated the string is though).

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi that's what I was implying as well! :D

Answer (score 2):

If `text` is string then you should parse them first, you can do so using [**`jQuery.parseHTML()`**](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/jQuery.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/index.html).

**Demo:**

```js
var text = `<div><div id="mainContent">Test Container</div></div>`;
text = $.parseHTML(text);
console.log($(text).find('div#mainContent'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @christian2222, you can accept the answer by *clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.*:)